# In Clojure, how would I map everything to a constant value?

Tags: clojure

For example

```
(map #(+ 10 %1) [ 1 3 5 7 ])
```

Will add 10 to everything

Suppose I want to map everything to the constant 1.  I have tried

```
(map #(1) [ 1 3 5 7 ])
```

But I don't understand the compiler error.

Comment: If you get a compiler error, it's a good idea to include this in the question so that people can help you more easily.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
(map #(1) [ 1 3 5 7 ])
```

Won't work for two reasons:

- `#(1)` is a zero-argument anonymous function, so it won't work with map (which requires a one-argument function when used with one input sequence).
- Even if it had the right arity, it wouldn't work because it is trying to call the constant 1 as a function like `(1)` - try `(#(1))` for example if you want to see this error.

Here are some alternatives that will work:

```
; use an anonymous function with one (ignored) argument
(map (fn [_] 1) [1 3 5 7])

; a hack with do that ignores the % argument 
(map #(do % 1) [1 3 5 7])

; use a for list comprehension instead
(for [x [1 3 5 7]] 1)

; use constantly from clojure.core
(map (constantly 1) [1 3 5 7])
```

Of the above, I think the versions using [constantly](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/constantly) or [for](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/for) should be preferred - these are clearer and more idiomatic.

Comment: `(map (constantly 1) [1 3 5 7])` seems like the right way to go, however, if you're just trying to get a sequence of 1s whose length is equal to the length of the sequence you're mapping over: `(repeat (count [1 3 5 7]) 1)` would work as well. It really all depends on the context in which you're using this as the particular problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 11):

The anonymous function `#(+ 10 %1)` is equivalent to:

```
(fn [%1]
  (+ 10 %1))
```

Whereas `#(1)` is equivalent to:

```
(fn []
  (1))
```

And trying to call `1` as a function with no args just won't work.

Answer (score 10):

I got this from [clojure.org](http://clojure.org/other_functions?responseToken=7307b055e9f28f399e3a274249d55308)
by googling the words "clojure constant function" as I am just beginning to look at clojure

```
(map (constantly 9) [1 2 3])
```

cheers

Comment: Clojure borrowed `constantly` from Common Lisp: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_cons_1.htm